# Задачка по t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо написать метод, что бы вывoдился кaлендарь тaкoгo видa :

```
| | | | |1|2|3 |
|4|5|6|7|8|9|1O|...
```

Дошел только до того, что после каждой недели будет перевод на другую сторону и что мы как то должны определить по месяцу с какого дня недели будет этот календарь выводиться(т.е. сколько пустых клеток будет)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

На данный момент сделал строку со всеми числами в месяце, нужно теперь посмотреть какой день недели является 1 числом и от него начать выводить

```
declare @week_one nvarchar(30) = '| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7|',
        @week_two nvarchar(30) = '| 8| 9|10|11|12|13|14|',
        @week_three nvarchar(40) ='|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|',
        @week_four nvarchar(40) = '|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|',
        @week_five nvarchar(30) = '|29|30|31|  |  |  |  |',
        @calendar nvarchar(max),
        @date nvarchar(10) = '2019-02-02',
        @day nvarchar(12),
        @dayCount int,
        @temp nvarchar(max),
        @count int 

set @day =  datename(WEEKDAY,@date)

/*if @day = 'Monday'
    begin 

    end 

if @day = 'Tuesday'
if @day = 'Wednesday'
if @day = 'Thursday'
if @day = 'Friday' 
if @day = 'Saturday'
if @day = 'Sunday'
*/
set @dayCount = day(dateadd(dd, -day(dateadd(mm, 1, @date)), dateadd(mm, 1, @date))) 
select @dayCount


set @temp = ''
set @dayCount = 28
set @count = 0
while @count <> @daycount 
    begin 
        set @count = @count + 1 
        set @temp = @temp + ('|'+cast(@count as nvarchar(5)))
    end
select @temp

/*set @calendar = @week_one + char(10) + @week_two + char(10) + @week_three + char(10) + @week_four + char(10) +  @week_five 

select @calendar */
```

p.s. Всех с наступающим!:)

Comment: datepart(dw, дата) получите день недели первого числа интересующего месяца

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определить с какого дня недели начинать вывод просто, `datepart(dw, дата)` даст день недели, к сожалению он вычисляется по разному для разных региональных настроек. Взяв его для первого числа требуемого месяца получаем с чего начать.

Но целая процедура тут в общем то ни к чему, вполне можно обойтись одним запросом:

```
with CTE as(
  select  -1 as dnum, cast('' as varchar) as txt, '2020-01-01' date
union all
  select c.dnum+1,
         cast( case when (c.dnum+1)%7=0 then '' else c.txt end +
               '|' +
               case when c.dnum+3-datepart(dw, c.date) between 1 and datepart(day, EOMONTH(c.date))
                    then right('_' + cast(c.dnum+3-datepart(dw, c.date) as varchar), 2)
                    else '__' end
            as varchar), date
    from CTE c
  where dnum < 34
)
select txt from CTE where (dnum+1) % 7 = 0 and dnum>0
```

Для наглядности пробелы заменены подчеркиваниями. Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0a28f/2139)
Ввиду того, что datepart возвращает разные данные в зависимости от региона может потребоваться коррекция. Для России в формуле вычисления дня используется +3, для Америки потребуется +4.

Запрос представляет из себя обычный рекурсивный CTE, перебирающий номера клеток в сетке месяца (dnum) до максимально возможных 5 недель. По абсолютному номеру клетки можно вычислить число, которое должно в ней стоять, исходя из дня недели первого числа. CTE сам формирует требуемую строку, начиная ее с начала для каждого дня кратного 7 (понедельника). В ячейку печатается число только если оно подходит для данного месяца, т.е. находиться в промежутке от 1 до последнего дня месяца. Если число не подходит, то печатается заполнитель.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вот так

```
DECLARE @Month int = 5
    ,@Year int = 1978

DECLARE @RealMonth TABLE (D int, DW int, Line int)

DECLARE @FirstDay date = DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, 1)
    ,@LastDay date = DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, 1)))

;WITH cteRange (DateRange) AS (
       SELECT @FirstDay
       UNION ALL
       SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, DateRange)
       FROM cteRange
       WHERE DateRange < @LastDay)
INSERT INTO @RealMonth (D, DW, Line)
SELECT DAY(DateRange) as DayNum
    ,DATEPART(dw,DateRange) as WeekDay
    ,0
FROM cteRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 31)

UPDATE @RealMonth
SET Line = 1 + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @RealMonth WHERE D <= RM.D AND DW = 2)
FROM @RealMonth RM

;with AlmostReady as (
        SELECT RM.Line
            ,COUNT(*) as CNT
            ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST((SELECT D FROM @RealMonth  WHERE Line = RM.Line FOR XML PATH('')) AS nvarchar(MAX)),'</D><D>', '|'),'<D>', '|'),'</D>', '|') as CalendarLine
        FROM @RealMonth RM
        GROUP BY RM.Line)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Line = 1 THEN CASE WHEN Cnt = 7 THEN '' ELSE REPLICATE('| ',7-CNT) END ELSE '' END 
        + CalendarLine 
        + CASE WHEN Line != 1 THEN CASE WHEN Cnt = 7 THEN '' ELSE REPLICATE(' |',7-CNT) END ELSE '' END 
FROM AlmostReady
```